# I wrote Jquery code that changes a button on hover, but I wrote the code separately for every button. How do I make it a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wrote the code separately for every single button on my website. How do I make this a Jquery function I can use for every single button I want to.

The code looks like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#linkXML").hover(
        function() {
            $("#linkXML").css({
                "-webkit-box-shadow": "inset 0px 0px 98px -34px rgba(51,173,255,0.79)",
                "-moz-box-shadow": "inset 0px 0px 98px -34px rgba(51,173,255,0.79)",
                "box-shadow": "inset 0px 0px 98px -34px rgba(51,173,255,0.79)"
            });
        },
        function() {
            $("#linkXML").css({
                "-webkit-box-shadow": "",
                "-moz-box-shadow": "",
                "box-shadow": ""
            });
        }
    );
});
```

So basically, I just copy pasted the code for every single button and changed only the element it's called upon on.

If you would be so kind to tell me how to make it a single function I can just give an element and it would call the function upon it.

Comment: Give them id's?

Comment: Use a css-class which you can select using $('.myClass')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use CSS as its intended, and not JS for this.

```
#linkXML
{
    // your styles, if any
}

#linkXML:hover
{
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 98px -34px rgba(51,173,255,0.79);
    -moz-box-shadow": "inset 0px 0px 98px -34px rgba(51,173,255,0.79);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 98px -34px rgba(51,173,255,0.79);
}
```

If you need this style on multiple elements, then apply a class.

Comment: Thanks, no idea how I forgot about this.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just select the `button` element in your jQuery selector?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").hover(
        function() {
            $(this).css({
                "-webkit-box-shadow": "inset 0px 0px 98px -34px rgba(51,173,255,0.79)",
                "-moz-box-shadow": "inset 0px 0px 98px -34px rgba(51,173,255,0.79)",
                "box-shadow": "inset 0px 0px 98px -34px rgba(51,173,255,0.79)"
            });
        },
        function() {
            $(this).css({
                "-webkit-box-shadow": "",
                "-moz-box-shadow": "",
                "box-shadow": ""
            });
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you give all the buttons an classname then they will be all selected

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".linkXML").hover(
        function() {
            $(".linkXML").css({
                "-webkit-box-shadow": "inset 0px 0px 98px -34px rgba(51,173,255,0.79)",
                "-moz-box-shadow": "inset 0px 0px 98px -34px rgba(51,173,255,0.79)",
                "box-shadow": "inset 0px 0px 98px -34px rgba(51,173,255,0.79)"
            });
        },
        function() {
            $(".linkXML").css({
                "-webkit-box-shadow": "",
                "-moz-box-shadow": "",
                "box-shadow": ""
            });
        }
   );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a class instead.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".linkXML").hover(
    function() {
      $(this).css({
        "-webkit-box-shadow": "inset 0px 0px 98px -34px rgba(51,173,255,0.79)",
        "-moz-box-shadow": "inset 0px 0px 98px -34px rgba(51,173,255,0.79)",
        "box-shadow": "inset 0px 0px 98px -34px rgba(51,173,255,0.79)"
      });
    },
    function() {
      $(this).css({
        "-webkit-box-shadow": "initial",
        "-moz-box-shadow": "initial",
        "box-shadow": "initial"
      });
    }
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="linkXML">Button</button>
<button class="linkXML">Button</button>
<button class="linkXML">Button</button>
```

---

**Recommended:**

If you can use CSS, it would be better to add a class and style the buttons there.

```css
.linkXML:hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 98px -34px rgba(51, 173, 255, 0.79);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 98px -34px rgba(51, 173, 255, 0.79);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 98px -34px rgba(51, 173, 255, 0.79);
}
```

```html
<button class="linkXML">Button</button>
<button class="linkXML">Button</button>
<button class="linkXML">Button</button>
```

---

If your links have an `.xml` file referenced in the `href` attribute, you can use a [**substring matching attribute selector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```css
a[href$=".xml"] {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 98px -34px rgba(51, 173, 255, 0.79);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 98px -34px rgba(51, 173, 255, 0.79);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 98px -34px rgba(51, 173, 255, 0.79);
}
```

```html
<a href="example.xml">Link</a>
<a href="example.xml">Link</a>
<a href="example.xml">Link</a>
```